# PowerBI : how to show and disappear column from table in PowerBI

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

I use this graph [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YR21.jpg)

I want to show in the graph the column of "average of IMDB rating" and the line of "IMDB Votes" but I need to add an option to show the columns of "max rating" and "min rating".

Can I add a button in the graph to change the columns?

Comment: Did you try this? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Changing-column-using-visual-button/m-p/793705/highlight/true#M382069

Comment: Show some sample data and your desired output from them.